# Is punctuation inconsistent in the already closed message?

Tags: support, bug, error-message

I wonder if the banner that reads "This question is already closed - please refresh the page" should have a full stop? Other banners like it usually have punctuation, for example "Thanks for flagging! We take your reports seriously."

If it's not a bug can someone explain how the [Stacks style guide](https://stackoverflow.design/content/examples/error-messages/) establishes the different use of punctuation for these two messages?

[image: screenshot This question is already closed]
[image: screenshot Thanks for flagging]

Comment: The closest seems to be *[Grammar and mechanics](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/)* → sub section *"Punctuation"* → *"Periods"*: *"Don’t use periods in interface copy unless it’s a full sentence or description."*. (There is also a [TOC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/table_of_contents#Noun) on the right to avoid too much scrolling.)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I thought of that guideline but the error message seems to be a full sentence to me.

Comment: Also, that hyphen should either be a semicolon or a dash (an em dash).